# function call in ng-class attribute of ng-repeat directive

Tags: javascript, .net, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Can someone figure out the problem with following line of code.

```
<tr ng-repeat="myrecord in myData" 
  ng-class="togglecolor('{{myrecord.name}}','{{myrecord[$index-1].name}}')? 'yellow':'red'">
```

Here togglecolor() function returns true or false.
yellow and red color not getting applied to the row.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be using `{{}}` interpolation inside your `ng-class` directive.

```
ng-class="togglecolor(myrecord.name,myrecord[$index-1].name)? 'yellow':'red'"
```

---

Better implementation would be directly return a class from `togglecolor` method.

```
ng-class="togglecolor(myrecord.name,myrecord[$index-1].name)"
```

**Code**

```
$scope.togglecolor = togglecolor;
function togglecolor(name, prevName){
   var flag;
   //some awesome logic set flag value here, either true/false
   return flag ? 'yellow': 'red';
}
```

Comment: Great!!, thanx, It is working now. There was one more problem in my script. I have to declare one global variable using -
app.value('rowcolor', { value: 'yellow' });

Answer (score 1):

Another way to use is not using a fucntion simple evaluate the expression in the ng-class

```
<tr ng-repeat="myrecord in myData" 
   ng-class="{true:'yellow', false:'red'} [toggleColor]>
```